# Inactive and simplify does not work

Tags: simplifying-expressions, hold

Consider the following code:

```
Simplify[Conjugate[Inactive[cn][n, nAvg]], 
 Assumptions -> Inactive[cn][__] > 0]
```

If you run it, it will not simplify, i.e recognize that because Inactive[cn][n,nAvg] is supposed to be positive there is no need to put the conjugate. However, running this script returns:

```
Conjugate[Inactive[cn][n, nAvg]]
```

- Why isn't it working ?
- How can I make it work ?

Comment: @CarlWoll To be honest, I don't know. The answer is way too high level for my knowledge of mathematica.

Comment: The problem is not `Inactive`, but the use of a pattern. If you used `f` instead of `Inactive[cn]`, the same thing would happen. It is a common misconception that patterns may be used in `Assumptions`, but this is not the case. `Assumptions -> f[_] > 0` does not in fact tell Mathematica that `f` is positive for any argument. However, patterns _can_ be used in `Element`. The following works: `Simplify[Conjugate[f[x]], Assumptions -> Element[f[_], Reals]]`. Note that this is a feature of `Element`, not of `Assumptions`.

Comment: You can use this approach if it is sufficient for your application to say that something is real instead of saying that it is positive. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may try instead to use a `Rule` such as

```
Conjugate[Inactive[cn][n, nAvg]] /. 
   Conjugate[Inactive[cn][x__]] -> Inactive[cn][x]
```

and then `Simplify`.